# Combining Operation for $S_4$

Tags: symmetric-groups

If $\sigma=(1\ 2\ 3\ 4)$, $\kappa=(1\ 2)$ for $S_4$ and I want to compute $(\sigma\kappa)^2$, does it become $\sigma^2\kappa^2 = \sigma^2$ (since $\kappa^2 = 1$), which is just $(1\ 3)(2\ 4)$?

Comment: "I want to calculate ()^2": well, just [do it, and show your attempts](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) (instead of trying to guess).

Answer (score 1):

Since $(\sigma\kappa)^2=\sigma\kappa\sigma\kappa$, asserting that $(\sigma\kappa)^2=\sigma^2\kappa^2(=\sigma\sigma\kappa\kappa)$ is the same thing as asserting that $\kappa\sigma=\sigma\kappa$. Well, this is not true. For instance, $\kappa\sigma$ maps $1$ into itself, whereas $\sigma\kappa$ maps $1$ into $3$.

Anyway, I think that the most natural approach for this problem is simply to compute $\sigma\kappa$ and then to square it.

Comment: Going with the approach of computing  then squaring it, is this correct:  = (1234)(12)(34) = (1)(2)(3)(4) ? If this is the right direction, how do I square (1)(2)(3)(4)? Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does the equality $\sigma\kappa=(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)(1\ \ 2)(3\ \ 4)$ come from?

Comment: Isn't =(1 2 3 4) and =(1 2)(3 4)? I might be misunderstanding reflections, how do I calculate reflections for symmetric group?

Comment: Didn't you write in your question that $\kappa=(1\ \ 2)$?

Comment: Oh Okay, so in this case it will be (1  2  3  4)(1  2)(3) (4)? Sorry I am a little confused by what reflections of symmetric groups mean algebraically

Comment: Yes, $\sigma\kappa=(1\ \ 2\ \ 3\ \ 4)(1\ \ 2)=(1\ \ 3\ \ 4)$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, $(\sigma k)^2$ means $(\sigma k)(\sigma k)$, because you "multiply" the element $(\sigma k)$ two times with itself. (It's actually the group operation instead of multiplication).

In this case, $\sigma k\sigma k$ is *not* the same as $\sigma^2 k^2$, because the group $S_4$ is non-commutative.

Does this help?